# Loaded weapon doesnt reload randomly inside loop

Tags: python

I decided to challange myself to create a small txt based game in python during my summer vacation to practice coding.

The issue im facing is when you attack and deal damage it is able to roll and detract the value from the monster hp, but its not able to reroll the weapon damage within the loop.

[Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIi8f.png) no matter how many times you attack.

Any help would be most appriciated!

I use a class to create weapons(have a seprate list off weapons, but added one of them as a example)

```
import random
class create_weapon:

    def __init__(self, damage, weapon_type):
        self.damage = damage
        self.weapon_type = weapon_type

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.damage)

axe = create_weapon(random.randint(1, 12), 'Axe')
```

Combat encounter code:

```
from Spel.NPCS.Monsters import * # this contains the created monsters, created via a class etc.

current_monster = Bandit
player = Orc # i havent created a player entity yet so i used orc as a stand in
current_monster_hp = current_monster.health
current_player_hp = player.health

def load_dmg_player():
    current_player_weapon = player.weapon_armor.weapon.damage
    return current_player_weapon

current_player_weapon = load_dmg_player()

def combat_encounter_form():

    print('\nYou are facing ' + current_monster.name + ''' what will you do?\n
        1: Combat
        2: Wait and see
        3: Try to Flee
    ''')
    player_input_combat_form = input('\nWhat is your choice?: ')
    if player_input_combat_form == '1':
        combat()
    elif player_input_combat_form == '2':
        print('Works also')
    elif player_input_combat_form == '3':
        print('probably working?')
        
def combat():

    print('''\nCombat choices:\n
    1: Attack the creature!
    2: Change your mind and flee?
    ''')
    player_input_combat = input('\nWhat is your choice?: ')

    if player_input_combat == '1':
        while player_input_combat != 'Flee':
            global current_monster_hp
            global current_player_hp
            print('''\nHow do you attack?:\n
        1: Attack
        2: Block
        3: Try to flee
            ''')
            mini_combat_input = input('\nWhat is your choice?: ')
            if mini_combat_input == '1':
                current_monster_hp = current_monster_hp - current_player_weapon
                print('You dealt: ' + str(current_player_weapon) + ' damage!')
                print(current_monster_hp)

            elif mini_combat_input == '2':
                print('Block stuff goes here.')
            elif mini_combat_input == '3'
                print('Cant flee due to not enough coding')

    elif player_input_combat == '2':
        print('yes')

    elif player_input_combat == '3':
        print('kek')
```

Comment: show some debugging outputs

Comment: Here's an easier way to reproduce your problem: `dmg = random.randint(0,10); print(dmg); print(dmg);`. You'll notice it always print the same damage in both print statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `create_weapon(random.randint(1, 12), 'Axe')`, `random.randint` will generate a fixed number, and I think what you're intending here is for it to always generate a random number.

There's a few ways you could approach it, but the most general would be to pass in a function for calculating damage.

For example, replacing the initialization with a `lambda` and replacing references to `self.damage` with `self.damage()` should give you random values each time:

```
In [22]: import random
    ...: class create_weapon:
    ...:
    ...:     def __init__(self, damage, weapon_type):
    ...:         self.damage = damage
    ...:         self.weapon_type = weapon_type
    ...:
    ...:     def __str__(self):
    ...:         return str(self.damage())
    ...:
    ...: axe = create_weapon(lambda: random.randint(1, 12), 'Axe')

In [23]: str(axe)
Out[23]: '1'

In [24]: str(axe)
Out[24]: '7'

In [25]: str(axe)
Out[25]: '9'
```

As another stylistic point, `import *` can get a bit unwieldy since it often dumps a lot of things into the global namespace. You might consider changing `from Spel.NPCS.Monsters import *` to something like `import Spel.NPCS.Monsters as monsters` and then you can refer to `monsters.Orc` etc.

Comment: Saw that you added the note on Import also, thanks!